# connecting to wifi with ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wireless

I cannot connect to wifi no matter what with my compaq presario c500
i have ran the following commands in the terminal but they do not do anything for me

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

This one says that the `bcmwl-kernel` could not be found so I ran another command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This one just did not do anything I have gone into my additional drivers tab and it does not show anything if you can help please reply.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Your pc seems to use the broadcom BCM4311 wireless card. 
It seems that bcmwl-kernel-source doesn't work well.

Check this link for more info and for detailed procedures:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/Broadcom_BCM4311_Natty_11.04

By the way, its better to always when asking for help, put some details about the hardware of your pc (processor, graphics card, wireless card, ram, etc...). It will help us to give you a correct answer.

regards